# Regex to prevent textbox from accepting email addresses

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

What is a regular expression that I can use to prevent a textbox from accepting an email address?

Comment: `[^@]+` won't match a modern email address.

Comment: Good validation doesn't reject things but specifies what _is_ allowed. Will your texts contain '@' ?

Comment: An additional criteria would be: Do you mean that the whole string cannot be an email address or that it can't contain an email address?

Comment: @Lazarus, the string can't contain an email address

Comment: And do you have max/min length, what char sets, spaces allowed?

Comment: I'd suggest reading this question with it's answers: [What is the best regular expression for validating email addresses?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Regex emailregex = new Regex("([0-9a-zA-Z]([-\.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})");
String s = "johndoe@example.com";
Match m = emailregex.Match(s);
if (!m.Success) {
   //Not an email address
}
```

However, be very warned that others much smarter than you and I have not found the perfect regex for emails.  If you  want something bulletproof then stay away your current approach.

Comment: If you want a more comprehensive email address matching regex (RFC compliant) then try this ((?>[a-zA-Z\d!#$%&'*+\-/=?^_`{|}~]+\x20*|"((?=[\x01-\x7f])[^"\\]|\\[\x01-\x7f])*"\x20*)*(?<angle><))?((?!\.)(?>\.?[a-zA-Z\d!#$%&'*+\-/=?^_`{|}~]+)+|"((?=[\x01-\x7f])[^"\\]|\\[\x01-\x7f])*")@(((?!-)[a-zA-Z\d\-]+(?<!-)\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}|\[(((?(?<!\[)\.)(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d?\d)){4}|[a-zA-Z\d\-]*[a-zA-Z\d]:((?=[\x01-\x7f])[^\\\[\]]|\\[\x01-\x7f])+)\])(?(angle)>) Short of verifying the domain, it covers most eventualities. More like this at http://www.regexlib.com

Answer (score 4):

Simply use a regex that is for an email address and check there are no matches.

Answer (score 2):

Read [How to Find or Validate an Email Address](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) and then check for no matches or negate the expression.

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this:

```
Regex emailRegex = new Regex(@"([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]    {1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})");
Match m = emailRegex.Match(this.emailAddress);
if (!m.Success) {
    MessageBox.Show("Email address is not correct");
} else { 
    Application.Exit();
}
```